# Let $G=(V,E)$ an undirected graph. Find a cut such that $|E(A)|\geq |E\setminus E(A)|$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ an undirected graph and let $A$ be a cut of $G$. Define $E(A)=(A\times (V\setminus A))\cap E$. Find an algorithm that finds a cut $A$ such that $|E(A)|\geq |E \setminus E(A)|$.

So I thought about that algorithm:

i. $A\leftarrow \emptyset$

ii. Find $v\in V$ such that $E(A\cup {v})>E(A)$. If there exists such a $v$ go to iii, otherwise go to iv.

iii. $A\leftarrow A\cup {v}$. return to ii.

iv. return $A$.

I am pretty sure that this is a maximal cut, that is, $E(A)$ is maximal for $G$ but I think there is a better algorithm. If I am not mistaken, finding such a $v$ in step ii will be $O(E)$ and we do it $O(V)$ times so we can say it is $O(VE)$. Maybe we can make it a little lower or is there a better algorithm anyone can think of?

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient algorithm is to:

1. Start with $A = B = \varnothing$.
2. For each vertex $v \in V$, compare the number of neighbors $v$ has in $A$ or $B$, and add it to the one where it has fewer neighbors.
3. Once every vertex is in either $A$ or $B$, return $A$.

If $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$ are the vertices of $V$ in the order that we can consider them in step $2$, we can partition the edge set of $G$ into $n$ parts  $E_1, E_2, \dots, E_n$ where $E_i = \{v_i v_j \in E : i > j\}$ is the set of edges whose second vertex to be considered is $v_i$.

Then in step 2 of the algorithm, when we're deciding where to put $v_i$, $E_i$ is the set of edges under consideration. Since we place $v_i$ so that $|E_i \cap E(A)| \ge \frac12|E_i|$, in the end, we'll get
$$
   |E(A)| = |E_1 \cap E(A)| + \dots + |E_n \cap E(A)| \ge \frac12|E_1| + \dots + \frac12 |E_n| = \frac12 |E|.
$$
In other words, $|E(A)| \ge |E \setminus E(A)|$.

As far as efficiency goes: given an appropriate data structure to use for the graph, step 2 has $O(\deg v)$ time complexity, and so the overall time complexity is $O(|V|+|E|)$.

Comment: Wow I never thought you can do that so efficiently. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Just one question, in the case $E=\emptyset$ then the time complexity is $O(|V|)$ because we check each vertex, so won't we say the complexity is $O(|V|+|E|)$?

Comment: @sssss fair enough; I guess I assumed there'd be a reasonable number of edges.

Comment: Generally you are right, but in the course I am taking they make us write it as O(|V|+|E|) xD